# Encoding custom image frames into video using gstreamer

Tags: c++, gstreamer, video-encoding

I am making a **C++** application in which I have a bunch of frames (in **unsigned char*** format) and I need to encode them as a video using gstreamer H265 encoder, running on GPU.
Most of the gstreamer samples are working with camera directly, but in my case there is no camera.

Using some samples I made the video encoder but the frames doesn't get pushed to the video file and the output video is empty.

Here is the code I implemented:

```cpp
GstElement *pipeline, *appsrc, *videoconvert, *x264enc, *mp4mux, *filesink, *autovideosink;
GstCaps *caps;
GstBuffer *buf;
GstMapInfo map;

gst_init(nullptr, nullptr);

pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("mypipeline");

// Create elements
appsrc = gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", "mysource");
videoconvert = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "myconvert");
x264enc = gst_element_factory_make("x264enc", "myencoder");
mp4mux = gst_element_factory_make("mp4mux", "mymux");
filesink = gst_element_factory_make("filesink", "myfileoutput");

if (!pipeline || !appsrc || !videoconvert || !x264enc || !mp4mux || !filesink) {
    g_printerr("Not all elements could be created.\n");
    // return -1;
}

// Set the properties for filesink
g_object_set(filesink, "location", "output.mp4", NULL);

// Build the pipeline
gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pipeline), appsrc);
gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pipeline), videoconvert);
gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pipeline), x264enc);
gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pipeline), mp4mux);
gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pipeline), filesink);

// Link the elements
gst_element_link(appsrc, videoconvert);
gst_element_link(videoconvert, x264enc);
gst_element_link(x264enc, mp4mux);
gst_element_link(mp4mux, filesink);

caps = gst_caps_from_string("video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR, width=(int)800, height=(int)600, framerate=(fraction)30/1");

gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    buf = gst_buffer_new_and_alloc(800 * 600 * 3); // Assuming BGR format
    gst_buffer_map(buf, &map, GST_MAP_WRITE);
    memset(map.data, i, 800 * 600 * 3); // Filling with dummy data
    gst_buffer_unmap(buf, &map);
    gst_app_src_push_buffer(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc), buf);
}

gst_app_src_end_of_stream(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc));

GstBus *bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
GstMessage *msg = gst_bus_timed_pop(bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE);
if (msg != NULL)
    gst_message_unref(msg);

gst_object_unref(bus);
gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
gst_object_unref(pipeline);
```

It seems that the command `gst_app_src_push_buffer` is doing nothing, which I don't have any clue why. Is there any mistake here?

Comment: I guess you wanted to set the `caps` on the appsrc? Also check https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/debugging-tools.html?gi-language=c for more info ho wto get feedback from GStreamer. But also, check return values can be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in your code:

1. Buffers are not properly timestamped (PTS/DTS/duration). Appsrc element allows to set `do-timestamp` property (to value `true`) in order to do the auto-timestamping for you but you cannot use it as you push buffers to the pipeline without waiting for the pipeline to reach the playing state first. Alternatively you could set additionally the `appsrc`'s `is-live` property to `true` to let `appsrc` push the buffers downstream once the playing state is reached, however the auto-timestamped buffers will be played with much bigger framerate than configured (30FPS). If you wanted 30FPS then something like the following would set the buffer timestamps properly:

```
    buf->pts = GST_MSECOND * 30 * i;
    buf->dts = buf->pts;
    buf->duration = GST_MSECOND * 33;
    gst_app_src_push_buffer(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc), buf);
```

2. `appsrc`'s `format` property should be set to the `GST_FORMAT_TIME` value.
3. caps are created but not set in the `appsrc` element

The following fixed version works fine:

```
#include <gst/app/gstappsrc.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>

#include <cassert>

int main() {
  GstElement *pipeline, *appsrc, *videoconvert, *x264enc, *mp4mux, *filesink,
      *autovideosink;
  GstCaps *caps;
  GstBuffer *buf;
  GstMapInfo map;

  gst_init(nullptr, nullptr);

  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("mypipeline");

  // Create elements
  appsrc = gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", "mysource");
  videoconvert = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "myconvert");
  x264enc = gst_element_factory_make("x264enc", "myencoder");
  mp4mux = gst_element_factory_make("mp4mux", "mymux");
  filesink = gst_element_factory_make("filesink", "myfileoutput");

  if (!pipeline || !appsrc || !videoconvert || !x264enc || !mp4mux ||
      !filesink) {
    g_printerr("Not all elements could be created.\n");
    // return -1;
  }

  // Set the properties for filesink
  g_object_set(filesink, "location", "output.mp4", NULL);

  // Build the pipeline
  gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pipeline), appsrc);
  gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pipeline), videoconvert);
  gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pipeline), x264enc);
  gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pipeline), mp4mux);
  gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pipeline), filesink);

  // Link the elements
  gst_element_link(appsrc, videoconvert);
  gst_element_link(videoconvert, x264enc);
  gst_element_link(x264enc, mp4mux);
  gst_element_link(mp4mux, filesink);

  caps =
      gst_caps_from_string("video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR, width=(int)800, "
                           "height=(int)600, framerate=(fraction)30/1");

  g_object_set(appsrc, "caps",  caps, nullptr);
  gst_caps_unref(caps);
  g_object_set(appsrc, "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME, nullptr);

  gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    buf = gst_buffer_new_allocate(nullptr, 800 * 600 * 3, nullptr); // Assuming BGR format
    gst_buffer_map(buf, &map, GST_MAP_WRITE);
    assert(map.size == 800*600*3);
    memset(map.data, i%255, 800 * 600 * 3); // Filling with dummy data
    gst_buffer_unmap(buf, &map);

    buf->pts = GST_MSECOND * 30 * i;
    buf->dts = buf->pts;
    buf->duration = GST_MSECOND * 33;
    gst_app_src_push_buffer(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc), buf);
  }

  gst_app_src_end_of_stream(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc));

  GstBus *bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
  GstMessage *msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, static_cast<GstMessageType>(GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS ));
  if (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg) == GST_MESSAGE_ERROR) {
    g_error ("An error occurred! Re-run with the GST_DEBUG=*:WARN environment "
        "variable set for more details.");
  }
  
  if (msg != NULL)
    gst_message_unref(msg);

  gst_object_unref(bus);
  gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref(pipeline);
}
```

Compiling, running and testing (on macos):

```
➜  ~ clang++ main.cpp $(pkg-config --libs --cflags  gstreamer-base-1.0 gstreamer-app-1.0)
➜  ~ ffprobe output.mp4
ffprobe version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/6.0_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomiso2
    creation_time   : 2023-11-03T23:15:15.000000Z
    encoder         : x264
  Duration: 00:01:16.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p(tv, bt709, progressive), 800x600 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 11 kb/s, 33.33 fps, 33.33 tbr, 3k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-11-03T23:15:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
➜  ~
```

I see that you wrote that code in C++. Please also consider using RAII technique to avoid maintaining resources manually. A simple RAII wrapper may help, simplify the code and make it less error prone. For instance:

```
template <auto Fn>
using FunctionObj = std::integral_constant<decltype(Fn), Fn>;

template <typename T, auto Fun>
using ResourceReleasedByFunction = std::unique_ptr<T, FunctionObj<Fun>>;

using ScopedGChar = ResourceReleasedByFunction<gchar, g_free>;
using ScopedGstElement = ResourceReleasedByFunction<GstElement, gst_object_unref>;
using ScopedGstCaps = ResourceReleasedByFunction<GstCaps, gst_caps_unref>;
using ScopedGstSample = ResourceReleasedByFunction<GstSample, gst_sample_unref>;
using ScopedGstBuffer = ResourceReleasedByFunction<GstBuffer, gst_buffer_unref>;
```

Example usage:

```
ScopedGstElement appsrc{gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", "mysource")};
...
// no need to call gst_object_unref at the end.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. It works as expected. One other issue here is that since I am continuously pushing frames into the appsrc (or encoding), it doesn't have time to finish the process in the iteration, so it seems it keeps all the frames on the memory (even if I unref the buf inside the loop) and fills the whole system memory gradually.
How can I get a signal from appsrc about finishing the encoding for each frame?